# An algorithm to compute the eigenvalues of $A + B$ recursively

Tags: recursive-algorithms, characteristic-polynomial

Is it posible to express a function

$$ Eig_n(A, B) := \{ \text{The } n\text{ eigenvalues of the } n \times n \text{ matrix } A + B \}$$

The input of $Eig$ can be either described as the eigenvalues of A, B (or their characteristic polynomial coefficients), and the orthogonal similarity matrices $S_A, S_B$ that relate the diagonal forms of A and B relative to the diagonal frame of $A+B$.

In recursive terms, based perhaps on $Eig_k(A,B)$ for $0 < k < n$?

Comment: If $k < n$, what matrix are you taking the eigenvaues of?

Comment: @William the input of $Eig$ are the eigenvalues of A, B (or their characteristic polynomial coefficients), and the orthogonal matrices $S_A, S_B$ are the similarity matrices that relate the diagonal forms of A and B relative from the diagonal frame of $A+B$